Not able to trim displayed value in Dropdown
I want to remove space only when user selects text from dropdown,I am not able to do that.
in option it should display as it is.


/*  $("#input_13").find("option").each(function (index, option) {
        $(option).html($(option).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,''));
 }); */
$('#input_13').change(function() {
  // Get the selected option
  var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
  // Get the current text, trim spaces, and set it back
  var trimmedText = $.trim(selectedOption.text());
  selectedOption.text(trimmedText);
  // Optionally, update the value attribute if needed
  // $(this).val(trimmedText);
  console.log($("#input_13 option:selected").text())
});
<select id="input_13">
  <option label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sw" value="number:1902">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sw</option>
  <option label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s" value="number:1903">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s</option>
  <option label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dsdsdsds" value="number:1906">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dsdsdsds</option>
  <option label="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;swww" value="number:1905">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;swww</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>



Here it should display trimmed value in selection.
Note:- Drop-down Selected value should be display only when displayed and in option it should display as it is.


It is not clear what you want to do. Your are showing the label and not the text, but only change the text

I want to remove the space from the displayed selected text only when the user chooses. otherwise, it should be displayed in the options as it is.

So change the label instead of the text: selectedOption.attr('label',trimmedText);

@mplungjan, when the user selects a different option, in options list it should be displayed in the same space. how can I do that? I am not able to do that can you help me with this?

Here is a version that uses data attributes to store the values


$(() => {
  const handleOptionLabels = (selectElement, save=false) => {
    $(selectElement).find('option').each(function() {
      if (save) this.dataset.label = this.textContent; // Save initial text to data-label
      else this.textContent = this.dataset.label; // Reset text from data-label
    });
  };
  $('#input_13').on('change', function() {
    handleOptionLabels(this); // reset
    // Get the selected option
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    // Get the current text, trim spaces, and set it back as the label
    var trimmedText = $.trim(selectedOption.text());
    selectedOption.text(trimmedText);
  });
  handleOptionLabels('#input_13', true); // initialise
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input_13">
  <option value="number:1902">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sw</option>
  <option value="number:1903">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;s</option>
  <option value="number:1906">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dsdsdsds</option>
  <option value="number:1905">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;swww</option>
</select>



